# Convert file to binary (make a hexdump)

Tags: python

I want to display file that convert to binary like binary editer.

For example, it convert PNG to 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00....

```
f = open(path, "r")
print f.read() # I want to convert this to binary
f.close()
```

Please advice me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Python 3

To get a binary in a hex representation:

```
bin_data = open(path, 'rb').read()
import codecs
hex_data = codecs.encode(bin_data, "hex_codec")
```

If `path` refers to a PNG file, then the first few bytes of `bin_data` will look like `\x89PNG\r\n` and the beginning of `hex_data` will look like `89504e470d0a`.  To format it nicely, add spaces:

```
import re
hex_with_spaces =  re.sub('(..)', r'\1 ', hex_data)
```

The corresponding first few bytes of `hex_with_spaces` will look like `89 50 4e 47 0d 0a`.

As an alternative to `codecs`, the `binascii` can be used:

```
import binascii
hex_data = binascii.hexlify(bin_data)
```

See jfs's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22449626/3030305) for a more detailed example using `binascii`.

#### Python 2

To get a binary in a hex representation:

```
bin_data = open(path, 'rb').read()
hex_data = bin_data.encode('hex')
```

If `path` refers to a PNG file, then the first few bytes of `bin_data` will look like `\x89PNG\r\n` and the beginning of `hex_data` will look like `89504e470d0a`.  To format it nicely, add spaces:

```
import re
hex_with_spaces =  re.sub('(..)', r'\1 ', hex_data)
```

The corresponding first few bytes of `hex_with_spaces` will look like `89 50 4e 47 0d 0a`.

Comment: Python 3.7.2: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: @Avión Thanks for spotting that.  I have just updated this answer (written in 2014) to include python3.

Answer (score 2):

To support both Python 2 and 3, you could use `binascii.hexlify()` instead of `.encode('hex')`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Make a hexdump"""
import re
import sys
from binascii import hexlify
from functools import partial

def hexdump(filename, chunk_size=1<<15):
    add_spaces = partial(re.compile(b'(..)').sub, br'\1 ')
    write = getattr(sys.stdout, 'buffer', sys.stdout).write
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        for chunk in iter(partial(file.read, chunk_size), b''):
            write(add_spaces(hexlify(chunk)))

hexdump(sys.argv[1])
```

Note: the file is opened in binary mode, to avoid corrupting the data due to newline conversions enabled for text file such as `'\r\n' -> '\n'`.